# Sending All Traffic Over VPN Tunnel (IKEv2) in OS X 10.11.5

Tags: macos, ios, network, wifi, vpn

I recently setup VPN connections on my Macbook Pro running OS X 10.11.5 via the `Apple Configurator`. However, I am having trouble sending all traffic across the VPN Tunnel rather than through the regular Wi-Fi Connection.

Although the `default route` is created when the VPN is connected, no traffic is sent across the VPN (the VPN has been confirmed to be working in Windows and Linux).

Here is the output of:

> netstat -rn

```
    Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.0.0.1           UGSc           43        0     en1
default            link#8             UCSI            0        0  ipsec0
10/16              link#5             UCS             8        0     en1
10.0.0.1/32        link#5             UCS             1        0     en1
10.0.0.1           <EDGE ROUTER MAC>  UHLWIir        47      194     en1      1076
10.0.143.243/32    link#5             UCS             1        0     en1
10.0.143.243       <MBP MAC ADDRESS>  UHLWI           0        1     lo0
45.32.180.111      10.0.0.1           UGHS            0        0     en1
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             18   781055     lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
172.11.22.1        172.11.22.1        UH              0        0  ipsec0
224.0.0            link#5             UmCS            1        0     en1
224.0.0            link#8             UmCSI           0        0  ipsec0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en1
255.255.255.255/32 link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
255.255.255.255/32 link#8             UCSI            0        0  ipsec0
```

There is no option to enable/disable forwarding all traffic over the VPN like there is with `PPTP`.

How can I forward all traffic over the VPN when the VPN is active similar to how Windows and Linux already does this?

The more I dig into OS X and VPN Networking the more it seems like it would be easier to host a dual VPN of IPSec for the Windows and Linux clients and OpenVPN for OS X and iOS.

Comment: I'm currently seeing the same problem, with no obvious solution yet. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: To answer my own comment, in a probably not very helpful manner: It seems like the routing tables were wrong, but I only solved this by rolling back the OS X test VM I was using. I suspect flushing the routing tables a bunch would help with this.

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problem, but I found the checkbox exists in the **"Apple Configurator2" VPN section**.

By installing the profile with enabling that option, all my traffic seems to pass under VPN.